# Parsing a text file with a custom format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have a bunch of text files that has a custom format, looking like this:

```
App Name    
Export Layout

Produced at 24/07/2011 09:53:21


Field Name                             Length                                                       

NAME                                   100                                                           
FULLNAME1                              150                                                           
ADDR1                                  80                                                           
ADDR2                                  80
```

Any whitespaces may be tabs or spaces. The file may contain any number of field names and lengths.

I want to get all the field names and their corresponding field lengths and perhaps store them in a dictionary. This information will be used to process a corresponding fixed width data file having the mentioned field names and field lengths.

I know how to skip lines using ReadLine(). What I don't know is how to say: "When you reach the line that starts with 'Field Name', skip one more line, then starting from the next line, grab all the words on the left column and the numbers on the right column."

I have tried String.Trim() but that doesn't remove the whitespaces in *between*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google "recursive descent parsing". You don't have a regular grammar, so grammar-driven parsing tools will not be likely to help.

Comment: Is the position of the line with `Field Name` fixed?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I would assume so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `SkipWhile(l => !l.TrimStart().StartsWith("Field Name")).Skip(1)`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> allFieldLengths = File.ReadLines("path")
    .SkipWhile(l => !l.TrimStart().StartsWith("Field Name")) // skips lines that don't start with "Field Name"
    .Skip(1)                                       // go to next line
    .SkipWhile(l => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))  // skip following empty line(s)
    .Select(l =>                                   
    {                                              // anonymous method to use "real code"
        var line = l.Trim();                       // remove spaces or tabs from start and end of line
        string[] token = line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return new { line, token };                // return anonymous type from 
    })
    .Where(x => x.token.Length == 2)               // ignore all lines with more than two fields (invalid data)
    .Select(x => new { FieldName = x.token[0], Length = x.token[1] })
    .GroupBy(x => x.FieldName)                     // groups lines by FieldName, every group contains it's Key + all anonymous types which belong to this group
    .ToDictionary(xg => xg.Key, xg => string.Join(",", xg.Select(x => x.Length)));
```

`line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` will split by space and tabs and ignores all empty spaces. Use `GroupBy` to ensure that all keys are unique in the dictionary. In the case of duplicate field-names the `Length` will be joined with comma.

---

**Edit**: since you have requested a non-LINQ version, here is it:

```
Dictionary<string, string> allFieldLengths = new Dictionary<string, string>();
bool headerFound = false;
bool dataFound = false;
foreach (string l in File.ReadLines("path"))
{
    string line = l.Trim();
    if (!headerFound && line.StartsWith("Field Name"))
    {
        headerFound = true;
        // skip this line:
        continue;
    }
    if (!headerFound)
        continue;
    if (!dataFound && line.Length > 0)
        dataFound = true;
    if (!dataFound)
        continue;
    string[] token = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (token.Length != 2)
        continue;
    string fieldName = token[0];
    string length = token[1];
    string lengthInDict;
    if (allFieldLengths.TryGetValue(fieldName, out lengthInDict))
        // append this length
        allFieldLengths[fieldName] = lengthInDict + "," + length;
    else
        allFieldLengths.Add(fieldName, length);
}
```

I like the LINQ version more because it's much more readable and maintainable (imo).

Comment: @Terribad: i've added some inline code comments, i hope that it provides a sufficient explanation. Otherwise say what you don't understand.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with LINQ, and that looks like a LOT of LINQ :P so I'm wondering if I can do this using `line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` but without the LINQ stuff.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I deleted that comment because I had the idea that I could do what I conjectured in the above comment, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @Terribad: however, i've provided also a non-linq version :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the non-LINQ version. I think I will try to understand your LINQ version since it's a lot more readable.

Comment: @Terribad: note that the non-LINQ version also uses `File.ReadAllLines` instead of `File.ReadLines` to support a `for`-loop. The disadvantage is that it needs to load all into memory before it can start processing as opposed to `ReadLines`. Maybe a `foreach` is sufficient, then you can also use `ReadLines` with the non-LINQ way. **Edit** i've tested it, you can use the `foreach` + File.ReadLines. Changed the code above.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the attention to detail! Alternatively, if I know that the first field always starts at the same line, I could just skip the lines until I reach that line, then use 

`line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` until `ReadLine()` returns `null`.

That would greatly simplify the code, don't you think?

Comment: @Terribad: i've just tried to "translate" your requirement into code. If you can make fix rules that can help to simplify the logic, of course. But do you really want to rely on the line number only? Use `File.ReadLines("").Skip(8)` to read all lines starting from the 9th.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for telling me about `Skip()`, If it were me I'd probably end up looping ReadLines() 8 times!

Comment: My senior engineer knows how these text files are generated and he said that it's reasonable to assume the first field always starts at the same line. I think that considerably simplifies the logic: simply start reading from that line and `Split()` using `SpringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`! But obviously your method is the way to go for more general cases.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that the position of the header line is fixed, we may consider actual key-value pairs to start from the 9th line. Then, using the `ReadAllLines` method to return a `String` array from the file, we just start processing from index 8 onwards:

```
  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
  Dictionary<string,int> pairs = new Dictionary<string,int>();

    for(int i=8;i<lines.Length;i++)
    {
        string[] pair = Regex.Replace(lines[i],"(\\s)+",";").Split(';');
        pairs.Add(pair[0],int.Parse(pair[1]));
    }
```

This is a skeleton, not accounting for exception handling, but I guess it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.StartsWith()` to detect "FieldName". Then `String.Split()` with a parameter of null to split by whitespace. This will get you your fieldname and length strings.

Comment: I tried this and it also gets all the whitespaces in between the two columns.